# Java use MongoCollection.countDocuments() executes slowly or even times out but deprecated count() method is ok

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-collection

```java
Bson filter = Filters.and(Filters.eq("appId", appId),
                        Filters.eq("ch", ch.getCh()),
                        Filters.gte("updateTime", startSeconds)
                );
long c = mainCollection.count(filter);  //run ok quickly, but it is Deprecated
// long c = mainCollection.countDocuments(filter);  socketTimeout
```

Java use `MongoCollection.countDocuments()` executes slowly or even times out, but the deprecated `count()`  method is ok.

Comment: You mean `countDocuments` _not_ `countCollections()`? Please update the post with correct information.

Comment: Oh, Sorry. Yes, when I use `countDocuments` to count the document number encountered socket timeout exception. But I use mongodb command `db.collection.find({...}).count()` perform well

Comment: Are there any indexes defined on the fields used in the _filter_ (`appId`, ...)?

Comment: Yes, the index of  `(appId, ch, updateTime)` has  been established, so use command for query the count quickly.

Comment: Does the `countDocuments` run faster?

Comment: And I found the `Collection.countDocuments()` use the `executeCount(clientSession, filter, options, CountStrategy.AGGREGATE)`, but the `Collection.count()` use the `executeCount(clientSession, filter, options, CountStrategy.COMMAND)`

Comment: `countDocuments()`  run slowly, and socketTimeout exception

Comment: Please run the `explain("executionStats")` on the `countDocuments()` and post the details.

Comment: Oh, you mean use the command to run these? 
Sry, I  am unfamiliar with how to perform these two methods together using Java collection.

Comment: Looks like you cannot run `explain` on `countDocuments`.

Answer (score 1):

`MongoCollection.estimatedDocumentCount()` and `MongoCollection.count()` in the legacy API both use the collection's metadata to provide the size of the collection. Compared to `MongoCollection.countDocuments()`, which performs a full collection scan, they are much faster, but cannot accept filters.

The specifics of the deprecated `MongoCollection.count()` vs `.estimatedDocumentCount()` appears to be a consistency issue within transactions, and clarifying that the method may not be 100% accurate.

See the [Java usage examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/java/sync/v4.4/usage-examples/count/) or [shell documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.estimatedDocumentCount/) for a similar explanation.